# Performance and use case between Bucket and App Engine Directory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pickle

I have two objects store as pickle in file. The files need to be modified and updated in about bi-weekly basis (not regular). I wonder if it is better to just store them in App Engine folder or upload them into bucket? Note that I have the intention to automate the files modification through cron or App Engine. How about the read-write speed between the two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read-write speed will indeed be higher from a disk in App Engine Flexible (App Engine Standard doesn't let you write to filesystem). On the other hand, it'll be tricky to manage if you want to rely on App Engine's scalability features. Let's say you have one instance, with the files on disk. The new spawned instance won't have those files on disk.

By storing those files on Cloud Storage, they'll be available to all App Engine's instance, no matter how many. You also ensure they all get the same version of those files. The downside is that access will be slower. If this is critical for your app, you may want to implement some cache mechanism to avoid retrieving the file from Storage every time. You can invalidate the cache on file update by implementing [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications).